# Java subprocess pipe file descriptor

Tags: java, file, process, pipe

This may seem a bit daft, but

- My Java code creates a sub-process
- I have a native function used elsewhere in the Java code which takes a pipe's file descriptor as an argument, and writes to that pipe.
- I want the function to write to the sub-process's standard input.

Is there a sensible way of achieving this?

This question may appear to be related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21041303/pipe-series-of-images-from-java-application-to-ffmpeg-subprocess), but differs in that I can't just use the `OutputStream`s provided by `Process`, because the native function takes an FD.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4845122/using-a-numbered-file-descriptor-from-java) might be helpful.